# implement a View to make Blur effect to UIImage and Will Change Image When TableView Slide

Tags: ios, uiimage

I want to implement a View to make Blur effect to a UIImage and the View can change image when a new Cell in a tableView Which has a image Slide into Screen,I use StackBluriOS to make blur

Comment: What do you want when new cell added in UITableview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Blur UIImage iOS 8

```
// show image
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boat6"];
// create effect
UIBlurEffect *blur = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
// add effect to an effect view
UIVisualEffectView *effectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:blur];
effectView.frame = self.imageView.bounds;
```